# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) error

Tags: php, syntax

```
function addDate( $Date, $adday ) {
    list( $year, $month, $day ) = year return date( "Y-m-d", mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, $day + $adday, $year ) );
}
```

Cant see the error

Comment: `year return date` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: _Can't see the error_ - which error? There are several. This code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addDate( $Date, $adday ) {
    list( $year, $month, $day ) = $Date; 
    return date( "Y-m-d", mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month, $day + $adday, $year ) );
}
```

This should be closer to what you are looking for. If you clarify your question I can clarify my answer.